# How can I hide the parent elements when there is no child element

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

For example:

```
<ul *ngIf="hasAnyPermission(['A:READ', 'B:READ', ...]）">
    <li *ngIf="hayPermission('A:READ')"> a </li>
    <li *ngIf="hasPermission('B:READ')"> b </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

In this case, I have to write all the permissions in the header again, e.g. hasAnyPermission([...]). Is it possible to write something like *ngIf="ShowOnlyWhenChildElementsAreNotEmpty()" in the header.

Comment: Not sure is this what you want. But for the parent element, I think possibly you need `*ngIf="<conditional a> || <conditional b>"`. If any condition a or b is true, then the parent element will show.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes this could solve the problem but if the list is long enough, this way could be time consuming. Therefore, I'm seeking for a easier way. I am thinking is there any way to just check if the children is empty or not. Then by this, the parent checking can be irrelevant to the children's checking.

Comment: What is the logic you are using for this condition? <conditional a>

Comment: Without a clearer knowledge of the conditions you are handling I can't guide you much but when I see so many template directives put together this way this rings a bell in my head to check if I can accomplish the same with ng-templates and ngTemplateOutlet, embeddedViews etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use .css [empty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty)

```
ul:empty {
    display:none;
}
```